# What can we do to help avoid member activation emails going to spam?

Tags: emails, registration, member, activation

We have a new Craft site that includes front-end member registration. We've heard from the client that many of the activation emails are getting stuck in spam filters (and I just tested with the same result). Is there anything that we can do to avoid this? Perhaps add SPF records?

Answer (score 4):

This the best article I've read on reliably delivering emails through code: http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/